# If Page URL Contains Queries Do Something

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, url

I am pretty beginner at JQuery & Javascript. Just trying to do something pretty simple. Test if the URL contains any queries like after the ?:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/**?example=test**
```

Then go on to implement some CSS style changes to the HTML. Here's what I have so far:

```
var $pageURL = window.location.search;

if ($pageURL.val() != "?") {

$("p").css("background-color", "blue");

}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Might be you want this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31333002/if-page-url-contains-queries-do-something/31333065#31333065

Comment: If the issue is solved, then accept the answer that has helped to solve the problem

Answer (score 4):

You can use `indexOf`:

```
var $pageURL = window.location.search;

if ($pageURL.indexOf('?example=') > -1) {
    $("p").css("background-color", "blue");
}
```

You can also use `regex`:

```
var url = window.location.href;
/\?.*?example=/i.test(url)
```

**UPDATE**

If you just want to check if URL contains querystrings:

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf('?') > -1) {
    // Do Something
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do like this:

```
if (window.location.toString().indexOf("?") !== -1) {
   // your code here
}
```

Or another variant that would work even faster:

```
if (window.location.search !== "") {
    // code here
}
```

Comment: Yeah that variant is very good. But I eventually I am going to get around to testing for a particular word in the URL string so your first is better in this case.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf('?') > -1)
{
   $("p").css("background-color", "blue");
}
```